# How to change SMP affinity of an IRQ on Ubuntu PV domU inside Xen XCP?

Tags: ubuntu, troubleshooting, irq, linux, smp

I'd like to change IRQ SMP affinity for reasons, outlined in this question: [CPU0 is swamped with eth1 interrupts](https://serverfault.com/questions/446173/cpu0-is-swamped-with-eth1-interrupts)

But I can't — I see `Input/output error` when I try to write to `/proc/irq/*/smp_affinity`.

Please point me to the HOWTO on the matter. (A formal reference on `/proc/irq/*/` would be cool as well.)

Gory details:

Note that this is a VM (PV domU) inside an Ubuntu-based Xen XCP host.

```
$ uname -a
Linux MYHOST 2.6.38-15-virtual #59-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 27 16:40:18 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.04
Release:    11.04
Codename:   natty

$ sudo cat /proc/irq/*/smp_affinity
01
01
01
01
01
80
80
80
80
80
80
40
40
40
40
40
40
20
20
20
20
20
20
10
10
10
10
10
10
08
08
08
08
08
08
04
04
04
04
04
04
02
02
02
02
02
02
01
01
01
01
01
01
```

**Update.** The error details:

```
$ N=$(grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo)
$ echo $N
8

$ printf %x $((2**N-1))
ff

$ printf %x $((2**N-1)) | sudo tee /proc/irq/*/smp_affinity
fftee: /proc/irq/288/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/289/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/290/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/291/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/292/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/293/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/294/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/295/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/296/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/297/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/298/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/299/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/300/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/301/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/302/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/303/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/304/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/305/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/306/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/307/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/308/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/309/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/310/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/311/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/312/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/313/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/314/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/315/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/316/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/317/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/318/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/319/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/320/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/321/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/322/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/323/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/324/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/325/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/326/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/327/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/328/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/329/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/330/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/331/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/332/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/333/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/334/smp_affinity: Input/output error
tee: /proc/irq/335/smp_affinity: Input/output error
```

**Update.** `irqbalance` is running:

```
$ sudo service irqbalance status
irqbalance start/running, process 560
```

Comment: So you're running this inside a Xen virtual machine?

Comment: Correct. I'll update the question.

Comment: Note that `irqbalance` is running. Maybe I'm just doing it wrong?

Comment: Is this a PV or HVM DomU?

Comment: PV. I'll update the question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What does `irqbalance --debug` show about what it is doing?

Comment: This document may help you ALOT.  http://www.intel.co.nz/content/dam/doc/application-note/82575-82576-82598-82599-ethernet-controllers-interrupts-appl-note.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that moving interrupts to different CPUs - especially for handling network events - would increase the performance.

The contrary will happen, since the network-code can not be held in a specific CPU any longer.

So as long as you do not experience dropped packets on your network interface, I would say - this is quite normal behaviour for a network that serves many packets.

You need to lower the number of interrupts - moving them around will not help (on the contrary, as I tried to outline).

I see two possible solutions:

- Raise your MTU-size to lower the number of interrupts
- PIN the vCPU 0 of the DomU to a dedicated CPU on the Dom0 (that is not used by any other VM or the Dom0).

**Update** 2012-12-17:
Since you asked for authoritative links - I tried to ask a general question [When not to use virtualisation](https://serverfault.com/questions/451651/when-not-to-use-virtualisation) - I think this is one of the cases, where you are hitting general VM limits. One of the answers to the question contains a different approach: Use containers, instead of virtualization.

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, but, would it help or not is outside of the scope of this question. Your help is very welcome here: http://serverfault.com/questions/446173/cpu0-is-swamped-with-eth1-interrupts or here: http://serverfault.com/questions/446081/uneven-cpu-core-utilization

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh Your core question is how to improve performance. Changing affinity (in the DomU) won`t help. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you, I'll look into that. But I'd like to see an authoritative answer on *why* affinity configuration does not work. It worries me that everyone seems to assume that it is possible, but I can't do that.

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh I doubt that affinity should work on a vCPU in a PV XEN DomU. I even read [somewhere](http://debaan.blogspot.de/2007/04/xen-tips-and-tricks.html) that irq-balance does not make any sense there.

Comment: I see. Links to the authoritative sources are much appreciated.

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh See my updated answer. It is not easy to find in the internet, so I asked here on SF...

Answer (score 8):

There is a file called [`Documentation/IRQ-affinity.txt`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/IRQ-affinity.txt;hb=refs/heads/linux-2.6.38.y) in the Linux source code.

```
/proc/irq/IRQ#/smp_affinity specifies which target CPUs are permitted
for a given IRQ source. It's a bitmask of allowed CPUs. It's not allowed
to turn off all CPUs, and if an IRQ controller does not support IRQ
affinity then the value will not change from the default 0xffffffff.
```

The catch here is that the bitmask is in hex. So, if you have N CPUs,

```
N=$(grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo)
```

to enable all IRQs for all CPUs, where you have N CPUs you can

```
printf %x $((2**N-1)) | sudo tee /proc/irq/*/smp_affinity
```

[Kernel 3.0 and later](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/IRQ-affinity.txt;hb=refs/heads/linux-3.0.y) has a file called [`smp_affinity_list`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/IRQ-affinity.txt;hb=refs/heads/linux-3.0.y). This file takes a comma separated list of CPUs or CPU ranges. Valid examples: `0`, `2,3,5-7`, `0-7`. The previous command is equivalent to:

```
echo 0-$((N-1)) | sudo tee /proc/irq/*/smp_affinity_list
```

Comment: Does not work, see update to the question.

Comment: +1 for that link to kernel's doc ;)

Comment: Does not work for me either, I am running on a real machine with no virtualization and the files are not writable.

Comment: A bunch of the files just say "Input/output error" and refuse to change CPU core

Answer (score 0):

> But I'd like to see an authoritative answer on why affinity
>   configuration does not work. It worries me that everyone seems to
>   assume that it is possible, but I can't do that.

Just on this specific question - and I have no idea whether Xen affects this answer - you get the `Input/output error` message when no device driver currently has a handler installed for this interrupt.

If a driver installs a handler on '105', for example, then directory `/proc/irq/105` is created, and contains an `smp_affinity`, among other things. You can now write to `smp_affinity`. If you close the device, the directory remains, with the `smp_affinity`, but you can no longer write to it. Open the device (via `open`, or whatever eventually calls `request_irq` in the driver) and you can now write to the file. Only tested on RHEL/SL 6.

If you don't know whether or not the device is currently open, check the directory. It will contain the device name if it's open.

Comment: I have a driver running for 113 and I am still not able to write to smp_affinity.